# SignalR Hub-2-Hub Communication with SQL Backplane in ASP.NET Owin

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin, webapi, signalr-backplane

I have an ASP.NET Owin Web Api which is load balanced, which means there are multiple instances of it which don´t know each other. The web api hosts a SignalR hub with an SQL Server Backplane (for synchronising between instances), so clients can exchange messages regardless of which instance of the web api they are connected to. Everything working so far.

Client session data is stored in the db. The web api needs this info for processing requests for the client. Because it would be too slow to read the session data from the db for every client request, the web api is reading it only once (on first request from the client session) and caching it in-memory. This also works across multiple instances of the web api as every instance is holding it´s own session data cache.

But now the clients should be allowed to change for example the language, which results in an updated language in the session data stored in the db. The web api instance which processes the "change-language"-request of course can react to the changed session data and clear the session from it´s cache, which will lead to a reread of the session data from the db on the next client request. But the other web api instances don´t know about the session data change, their caches now hold outdated session data.

The web api instance which processes the "change-language"-request would somehow need to notify the other instances to drop their cache for session xyz. Unfortunately the instances don´t know each other, but all instances host SignalR hubs which are synchronised through the SingalR SQL server backplane.

Unfortunately a SignalR hub cannot directly send and receive messages. A HubConnection (client) is needed to do that. So the idea is when every web api instance is connecting to it´s own SignalR hub, it would be able to send messages to itself, which are then spread out to the other instances via the SQL server backplane synchronisation. But a HubConnection can only be established with an URL (http://host:port/signalr) but the web api instance doesn´t know it´s own base url.

So finally my question is:
Is there any way to establish a HubConnection to a hub running in the same process without providing an URL (I have access to the hub object)?
If not, is there any way for a SignalR hub to spread out messages and listen to messages through the backplane without a client (hub-2-hub communication)?
If not what else could I do to notify other instances of my load balanced web api and advice them to drop their session data cache?

Comment: `a SignalR hub cannot directly send and receive messages.`??? Quite the opposite, and all examples show just that, eg [How to call client methods from the Hub class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#how-to-call-client-methods-from-the-hub-class)

Comment: What's the actual question? What do you mean by `hub-2-hub communication` ? Are you trying to use SignalR to do something it's not meant to do perhaps? Its job is to send messages to clients, not replace Web API or other HTTP APIs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: but I need a hub to send a message to another hub which is synchronized through the backplane, not to a client. I explained this quite clearly imo. I also asked for alternate ways if this isn´t possible or isn´t meant to be used like that.

Comment: Which is not what SignalR is about.  The question isn't clear at all, there's a lot of text that essentially asks `Can SignalR be used to send notifications between hubs in a farm?` and the answer is `No, that's not what it's for`. The *real* question though seems to have nothing at all to do with SignalR - how to update client session information, or even how to *fix* the database performance issues

Comment: If you fix the *real* issue you won't have to use in-memory session only, because that's what you do. If the session is loaded only once, essentially it's in-mem only. What does slow mean in this case? Why is session loading slow? Is there too much data? Missing indexes? Underpowered database server?

Comment: If you have such high traffic (*how* much?) that a regular database table is an issue, you can use an in-memory table in SQL Server or a Redis cache to store the session. What you try to do is emulate a distributed Redis cache. Why not use an *actual* Redis cache? Trying to get the web servers to act like Cache nodes is non-trivial. Microsoft tried this for a long time with AppFabric Cache before abandoning it for Redis.

Comment: Again, what's the *real* problem though? Quite often "big data" or "high traffic" problems are caused by bugs, misconfiguration or simply inadequate hardware. Fixing the real problem is easier and cheaper than trying to cover it up

Comment: For example, what if *two* changes are made to the same setting? Even if SignalR acted like eg MSMQ and sent messages between nodes, how would that solve the concurrency issue? SignalR *depends* on a backplane to solve that issue, it can't do it itself. You're asking SignalR not just to send messages between hubs, you're asking it to become Redis

Comment: The [Distributes caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0#distributed-ncache-cache) article mentions several different ways to store session state: a database, Redis or NCache. Have you tried [NCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0#distributed-ncache-cache)?

Comment: The IDistributedCache interface pointed me into the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved through distributed caching (IDistributedCache), as mentioned by Panagiotis Kanavos in the comments.